# How to insert only records to SQlite and ignore already exist records?

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am inserting records in my sqlite table from server. It is working like a charm and records successfully inserted. Now what I want that when user launch the application second next time then it is inserting duplicate records again.

**I want to insert only new records if avaible and ignore already exist records.**

```
db.execSQL("Insert into myTable(ProjectNo,ProjectId,ThirdParty,SealingNumber,BookNumber,SupplyType,ConsAcNo,KnoNo,MeterSrMo,ConsName,ConsAddress1,ConsAddress2,ConsAddress3,TelephoneNo, ConsMobileNo,SanctionLoad, MeterMake, MeterType, PhaseType, IsCompleted, Contractor ") ) values ('" + c.getString("PROJECT_NUMBER") + "'," + c.getString("PROJECT_ID") + ",'" + c.getString("THIRD_PARTY") + "'," + c.getString("SEALING_NUMBER") + "," + c.getString("BOOK_NUMBER") + "," + c.getString("SUPPLY_TYPE") + "," + c.getString("CONS_ACCOUNT_NO") + "," + c.getString("KNO_NUMBER") + ",'" + c.getString("MTR_SERIAL_NO") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_NAME") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_ADDRESS1") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_ADDRESS2") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_ADDRESS3") + "','" + c.getString("TELEPHONE_NO") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_MOBILE_NO") + "','" + c.getString("SANCTION_LOAD") + "','" + c.getString("METER_MAKE") + "','" + c.getString("METER_TYPE") + "','" + c.getString("METER_PHASE") + "','N', '"+ c.getString("CONTRACTOR1") +"')");
```

I tried below query but I failed.

```
db.execSQL("Insert into FieldUtilityData (ProjectNo,ProjectId,ThirdParty,SealingNumber,BookNumber,SupplyType,ConsAcNo,KnoNo,MeterSrMo,ConsName,ConsAddress1,ConsAddress2,ConsAddress3,TelephoneNo, ConsMobileNo,SanctionLoad, MeterMake, MeterType, PhaseType, IsCompleted, Contractor WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT  ConsAcNo FROM  FieldUtilityData WHERE ConsAcNo = " + c.getString("CONS_ACCOUNT_NO") + ") ) values ('" + c.getString("PROJECT_NUMBER") + "'," + c.getString("PROJECT_ID") + ",'" + c.getString("THIRD_PARTY") + "'," + c.getString("SEALING_NUMBER") + "," + c.getString("BOOK_NUMBER") + "," + c.getString("SUPPLY_TYPE") + "," + c.getString("CONS_ACCOUNT_NO") + "," + c.getString("KNO_NUMBER") + ",'" + c.getString("MTR_SERIAL_NO") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_NAME") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_ADDRESS1") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_ADDRESS2") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_ADDRESS3") + "','" + c.getString("TELEPHONE_NO") + "','" + c.getString("CONS_MOBILE_NO") + "','" + c.getString("SANCTION_LOAD") + "','" + c.getString("METER_MAKE") + "','" + c.getString("METER_TYPE") + "','" + c.getString("METER_PHASE") + "','N', '"+ c.getString("CONTRACTOR1") +"')");
```

Comment: Maintain a **PRIMARY KEY** or column with **UNIQUE** constraint. It will throw an error(_primary constraint failed..._) in case of duplicate record.

Answer (score 1):

**check using where conditions, if that matches than update table or else insert.**

Do this way,

```
db.open();

        //for insert in db
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("ProjectNo", "ProjectNo");
        cv.put("ProjectId", "ProjectId");
        cv.put("SealingNumber", "SealingNumber");
        cv.put("ConsAcNo", "ConsAcNo");
        cv.put("KnoNo", "KnoNo");
        cv.put("MeterSrMo", "MeterSrMo");
        cv.put("ThirdParty", "ThirdParty");
        cv.put("BookNumber", "BookNumber");
        cv.put("SupplyType", "SupplyType");
        cv.put("ConsName", "ConsName");
        cv.put("ConsAddress1", "ConsAddress1");
        cv.put("ConsAddress2", "ConsAddress2");
        cv.put("ConsAddress3", "ConsAddress3");
        cv.put("TelephoneNo", "TelephoneNo");
        cv.put("ConsMobileNo", "ConsMobileNo");
        cv.put("SanctionLoad", "SanctionLoad");
        cv.put("MeterMake", "MeterMake");
        cv.put("MeterType", "MeterType");
        cv.put("PhaseType", "PhaseType");
        cv.put("IsCompleted", "IsCompleted");
        cv.put("Contractor", "Contractor");

        //your where condition (change as per your requirement)
        String whereClause = "ProjectNo = " + "PROJECT_NUMBER" + " AND " + "ProjectId" + " = PROJECT_ID" + "AND "
            + "SealingNumber =" + "SealingNumber" + "AND" + " ConsAcNo = " + "ConsAcNo" + "AND" + "KnoNo = " + "KnoNo"
            + "AND" + "MeterSrMo = " + "MeterSrMo";

        Log.e("where ", "-->>" + whereClause);
        //to get count if it is more than zero than update else insert to table
        String query = "SELECT count( * ) as count from myTable where " + whereClause;

        //check count if that value exists in db
        if (query.trim().length() <= 0) {
            db.insert(myTable, intCode, cv); //intCode is primary key
        } else {
            db.update(myTable, cv, whereClause, null);
        }
        db.close();
```

Comment: check my updated answer@Moin Khan hope that will solve your issue.

Comment: how about this code my friend?@Jitendraramoliya@?Moin Khan

Answer (score 0):

```
  public int getFullCount(String table, String where) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(false, table, null, where, null, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                no = cursor.getCount();
                cursor.close();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return no;
    }
```

use this function and pass the table name & conditions. Before inserting check count, if count return will be greater than 0 then don't add records else add records

Comment: He don't want to delete existing records. He wants only new non-duplicate records to be inserted, keeping the existing records as it is.

Comment: @MonishKamble where it is written that it ll delete the records. Where you are writing code for inserting record. before that get count using this function. If count ==0 then insert record else leave it because if count >0 then it means record is already there

Comment: if count greater then 0 then it will  not insert new available record also and I want to insert new record and ignore record which already in my table.

Comment: are you getting this info from server side ?

Comment: yes, I am getting json from server and inserting in sqlite.

Comment: Then you need to ask for a parameter when new record is there and when old record is coming. Then you can apply this otherwise at local end how would you judge that from server site new info is there for that particular user

Comment: @MoinKhan : Can you post the JSON or specify the unique element in the JSON

Comment: Then you need to check in database if that record already available then skip it and add when not available in database. like                                           public String isAvailable(String Id) {
    
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + ID + "=?";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{channelId});
        if (c != null && c.getcount() > 0) {
           c.close(); return true;
        }
       
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Set **ConAcNo** as the primary key of your table and use SQLiteDatabase class's `insert(...)` method. Remember it doesn't throw any error and returns `-1` in case of any error. If you try to insert duplicate record, it will cause an error and return `-1` which you can ignore.

[Documentation of insert() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

[Guide for Saving Data in SQL Databases](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow)